# Serialization ManyToOne

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

i have two entity: Order and OrderItem.

```
@Entity(name="ORDERS")
public class Order {
...

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "order", cascade =CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<OrderItem> orderItems=new ArrayList();


@Entity(name="ORDER_ITEMS")
public class OrderItem {        
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private Order order;
```

I have also two Rest controllers one to get all the orders and one to get all the order items. The controller to get all the orders return a json that contains all the orders .. for each order the related list of order items.
The rest controller of OrderItem show all the orderItems but not show the related order even if in the class there is the field

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false)
@JsonBackReference
private Order order;
```

So the issue is caused by the serialization .. can you help to solve it ? I want to show also the related order in OrderItem controller.

Comment: did you try using `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` in your OrderItem class

Comment: not works... only  getOrder controller show in the json the order items but get order items not show order in the json